# button is called twice with performClick()

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a ImageButton plus. When click i need to do a inflate of a view.

My problem is that when i use performClick the Imagebutton is called twice, and execute two inflates simultaneously.

I don't why this happens.

Here is a little of my code:

```
    private ImageButton addPhone;
    addPhone = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ac_ibAddClientPhone);

    addPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                inflationFields = new InflatationFields(getActivity());
                inflationFields.inflateNewField("phone", containerPhone, view, adapterPhone);
            }
        });
```

and in another part of the code i call the button and try to click with perform click

```
        try{
     if(ccPhone.moveToFirst())  
         do{
             if(flag_first==true){ 
                 phone =  ccPhone.getString(ccPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                 Log.d(ClientEditContact.class.getName(), "PHONE: " +phone); 
                 type = ccPhone.getInt(ccPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                 etPhone = (EditText)viewPrincipal.findViewById(R.id.ac_etAddClientPhone);
                 etPhone.setText(phone + "" +etPhone.getTag().toString());
                 spPhone.setSelection(convertTypeToIdSpinner(type)); 
                 flag_first=false; 
             } 
             else if(flag_first == false){
                     addPhone.performClick(); 
                     phone = ccPhone.getString(ccPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     type = ccPhone.getInt(ccPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                     etPhone = (EditText)viewContainerPhone.findViewWithTag("etTagPhone" + count);
                     etPhone.setText(phone + "" + etPhone.getTag().toString());

                     count = count + 1;
                     if(count==ccPhone.getCount()){
                         break;
                     }
             } 
         }while(ccPhone.moveToNext());       
     Log.d(ClientEditContact.class.getName(), "LAST PHONE ---> " +phone);
     }finally{
         if(ccPhone != null && ! ccPhone.isClosed()){
         ccPhone.close();
         }
     }
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the part of code from where you are calling `addPhone.performClick();`. May be that part is getting called twice.

Comment: Hello jaibatrik. I check, and the problem is not in there part of the code. The problem is in performClick() and in setOnClickListener. But i go to update my question with this code....

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late, but the system calls performClick() on its own when the button is clicked so you shouldnt use it in your code.